# How to validate a text for the webelement which is under Div/small/d tags C#

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, testing, xpath

Below is the HTML code of the footer information of my webpage.

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <small>
            © 2020 <b>CT Bank Limited</b>&nbsp;- <b>Version:</b> 2.1.7418
            - <b>Release Date:</b><span id="releaseDate"> 23/04/2020</span>
            - <b>Web Host:</b><span id="webHost"> CBWFDEV01</span>
            - <b>Client Name:</b><span id="clientName"> cn8c04ba119a80</span>
            - <b>Request Time:</b><span id="requestTime"> 28/04/2020 9:23 AM</span>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to validate each text field in the footer information like CT Bank Limited/Version/Release Date/Web Host/Client Name/Request Time are present in the web page.

What is the right way to validate the above text in footer information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is to have a Selenium script to navigate to the URL and do the verifications as a unit test.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

class HelloSelenium
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://your_page");
            // You have to validate the elements one by one
            String releaseDate = driver.FindElement(By.ID("releaseDate")).Text();
            // Validate the releaseDate against the expected value.

            String webHost = driver.FindElement(By.ID("webHost")).Text();
            // Validate the webHost against the expected value.

            String clientName = driver.FindElement(By.ID("clientName")).Text();
            // Validate the clientName against the expected value.

            String requestTime = driver.FindElement(By.ID("requestTime")).Text();
            // Validate the requestTime against the expected value.


        }
    }
}
```

More awesome examples at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation

Comment: glad I could help